# Magento: 2 products always at top of home page, side by side

Tags: html, css, magento

What's the best (free) way to do that in CE rwd? Can I use the new-products widget, and limit that to display ONLY the same 2 constant products that I want to be always at the top? I don't want any other products to displace those two.

Also, how can I center them horizontally? Aligning text to center doesn't center the product images, only the text. Meanwhile, this way:

```html
 <div style="margin: 0 auto;">
```

does nothing.

One step further: can I make the 2 featured products larger than the popular products list that I want to next show beneath the 2 featured products?

Thanks.